# change css property of placeholder

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, django-cms

I have navigation horizontal bar.
I placed my placeholder inside navigation bar. 
In admin panel i clicked + and added few plugins(links).
The problem is there is no space between plugins in my case links.
How can i set space between plugin texts in same placeholder.
In Css i can only manipulate whole division "a" but i want to force white spaces between links.

edit:
anoter option is to set key and value to placeholder. Can I assign them and manipulate with css? I already tried [value ~= placeholder_value] but cant make it work

```
<div class="a"> {% block navibar_1 %}{% placeholder nav_item1 %}{% endblock %}</div>
```

structure admin site:

```
Navbar1
  links1
  links2
  links3
  links4
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple ways you can approach this:

- override the plugin HTML (not sure if it's off the shelf or custom) and wrap those elements inside a class of your preference
- analyse your output markup and amend CSS selectors (may not be possible) to change styling

Any reason you are not using the menu functionality?

Comment: Hey,

I've already made an division class. Put it in css and change     word-spacing.If i use margin in class the whole division is moved and not placeholders.What do you mean menu functionality?I havent found any of additional options in menu.